# Console error regarding linking for React Navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, react-navigation-v6

I have an issue with deep linking using React Native, React Navigation on IOS. The error doesn't show up on Android. When I start the app I get a console error saying:

```
Looks like you have configured linking in multiple places. This is likely an error since deep links should only be handled in one place to avoid conflicts. Make sure that:
- You don't have multiple NavigationContainers in the app each with 'linking' enabled
- Only a single instance of the root component is rendered
```

I reduced my app to:
App:

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ['apptest://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Home: 'home',
      },
    },
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={linking}
      fallback={<Loading />}
      ref={navigationRef}
    >
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

index:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import App from './App'
import { name as appName } from './app.json'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)
```

I already double checked the AppDelegate.mm file and Info.plist to include the correct scheme. The linking actually works, but I want to know what is causing the error message. I checked the whole project, there is only one declaration of the NavigationContainer and no other linking related code. The app root is only rendered once and I tried on a real device as well. I reduced the app to only have the NavigationContainer, yet the console error still gets printed, the second I add the linking prop to the NavigationContainer.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By setting linking.enabled to false, the error disappears and deeplinking still works. Hope it helps.

My stack :

- React native 0.72.7
- React Navigation 6.1.9

I'm investigating to understand why though.